# Error in default function template arguments when trying to convert C++11 code to C++03

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03

I am trying to convert C++11 code to C++03 and stuck on a default template argument.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_const.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/conditional.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/support/string_traits.hpp>

template<bool B, class T = void>
struct enable_if {};

template<class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };

template<typename T>
struct is_char
{
    typedef typename  enable_if<sizeof (T) == sizeof (char)>::type eif;
};


template<bool B, class T, class F>
struct conditional { typedef T type; };

template<class T, class F>
struct conditional<false, T, F> { typedef F type; };

template <typename ObjType,
        typename PtrType,
        typename CharType =
            typename conditional<boost::is_const<PtrType>::value,
                                      const typename ObjType::char_type,
                                      typename ObjType::char_type>::type,
        typename is_char<PtrType>::type >
CharType* char_ptr_cast(PtrType* p)
{ return reinterpret_cast<CharType*>(p); }

int main ()
{}
```

I am getting following error:

```
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/c++0x_warning.h:31:2:
> error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the
> upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently
> experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
> compiler options. 
> 
> test.cc:35: error: no default argument for anonymous
> 
> **default template arguments may not be used in function templates without -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x**
```

Could you please help me to resolve these errors?

Comment: Do as the error says, and compile with `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x` compiler option

Comment: Why not instead install [devtoolset-8](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/8/html/8.0_release_notes/dts8.0_release) and get yourself a newer (and fully supported) gcc 8.2 compiler? Instead of sticking to the old gcc 4.4 system compiler. Then you can even use C++17 if you like.

Comment: @CinCout As error suggest it is experimental so i can not use -std=c++0x in my project.

Comment: So you actually want to convert the code back to C++03, not C++0x.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default template arguments for *function templates* were added in C++11. If you can't use C++11, or your compiler doesn't support it properly, you can't define `typename CharType = /* whatever */`. The way towards C++03 compliance without retyping that long meta-function is to refactor `CharType` into its own trait, and use that.

```
template<typename ObjType, typename PtrType>
struct CharType {
    typedef typename conditional<boost::is_const<PtrType>::value,
                                 const typename ObjType::char_type,
                                 typename ObjType::char_type>::type
    type;
};

template <typename ObjType typename PtrType>
typename CharType<ObjType, PtrType>::type* char_ptr_cast(PtrType* p)
{ return reinterpret_cast<typename CharType<ObjType, PtrType>::type*>(p); }
```

---

Also, the `<type_traits>` header is a C++11 only header. Since you hit a `#error` directive following a failed standard's version check in the standard library, that is the most likely culprit. You cannot include it.

Comment: i am getting following error :
test.cc:36: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ObjType
test.cc:36: error: expected > before typename

Comment: some more errors :
test.cc:37: error: PtrType was not declared in this scope
test.cc:37: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for template<class ObjType, class PtrType> struct CharType
test.cc:37: error:   expected a type, got ObjType
test.cc:37: error: template argument 2 is invalid
test.cc:37: error: invalid type in declaration before ( token
test.cc:37: error: template declaration of int* char_ptr_cast
test.cc:37: error: PtrType was not declared in this scope
test.cc:37: error: p was not declared in this scope

Comment: @UndefinedBehaviour - You have unrelated errors in your code. I described how to fix the backwards compatibility issue in the snippet you posted, so whatever happened next is related to how you applied it. I will not troubleshoot your changes in back and forth comments.

Comment: after removing all errors, I am still getting experimental error :
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/c++0x_warning.h:31:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.